# Return JSX from Promise in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, promise, jsx, react-context

I want to conditionally render Components in my react native app, I have tried, but nothing seems to work. **Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object w
ith keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.** I don't understand what I am missing here

```
<RootContext.Consumer>
            {({handleChange, data}) => {
                let {property, currentFloor} = data
                let flag = false
                return this._getConfigDataFromFile(property, currentFloor)
                    .then(data => {
                        data.forEach(c => {
                            if (c.zone === this.props.title) {
                                flag = true
                            }
                        })

                        return (
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPress}>
                                <View>
                                    {flag ? <SomeComponent /> : <SomeOtherComponent />}
                                </View>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        )
                    })
            }}
</RootContext.Consumer>
```

Comment: You are returning a promise obj (`return this._getConfigDataFromFile` )  which should be a React child. Take the function out and put it in componentdidmount or sth like that or use await instead of then(not recommended)

Comment: why do you say `await` is not recommended?

Comment: Also, I wont have access to `data` object in `componentdidmount` so I don't think I can move `_getConfigDataFromFile` function anywhere else

Comment: coz you are responsible to show sth on the screen while loading.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you need to return the React component whereas you're returning a promise.
Do something like..

```
const App = (
     <ReactConsumer>
        <Component1 />  
     </ReactConsumder>
);

const Component1 = () => {
   React.useEffect(() => {
     const pr = await somePromise();
   }, []};

   return (
    { pr ? 
        <AnotherComponent>pr something</AnotherComponent> 
        : null or something else 
    });
```

You can use useEffect or something like componentDidMount.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have access to `data` object outside of `<RootContext.Consumer>`. So I have to use `_getConfigDataFromFile` inside the render function (the way its done now)

Comment: @PranjalGore I've updated the answer as per your requirement. You can just create a new component then and use promise outside the return in that :)